# formsubmit.co and form error validation only work locally not on live site

Tags: javascript

While using vscode's live server the form is being processed by formsubmt.co and the form validation errors work when necessary. After updating the changes and viewing the live site It doesn't work. I'm not getting any console errors on submit the page just refreshes. I have added and removed the required attribute from the inputs while troubleshooting, and it doesn't change anything. [live site](https://emrikcah.github.io/Pattykakes/order.html) [codepen](https://codepen.io/JavelinHertech/pen/MWmYgrV)

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");
const cusName = document.getElementById("customername");
const cusEmail = document.getElementById("customeremail");
const cusOrder = document.getElementById("customerorder");

//display the error
const showError = (input, msg) => {
   input.classList.add("border", "border-red-600");
   let small = input.nextElementSibling;

   small.classList.remove("invisible");
   small.classList.add("block");
   small.innerText = msg;
  
};


//check email
const checkEmail = (email) => {
   const re =
      /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
   return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
};

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
   // e.preventDefault();

   if (cusName.value === "") {
      showError(cusName, "Your name is required");
   }
   if (cusEmail.value === "") {
      showError(cusEmail, "Your email is required");
   } else if (!checkEmail(cusEmail.value)) {
      showError(cusEmail, "Your email is not valid");
   }
   if (cusOrder.value === "") {
      showError(cusOrder, "Please place your order here. Item name and quantity.");
   }
});

//remove the red border on focus
form.addEventListener('focus',(e)=>{
   if (e.target.classList.contains('border')) {
      e.target.classList.remove('border');
   }
},true)



<form target="_blank" action="https://formsubmit.co/123@youremail.com" id="form" class="flex flex-col" method="POST">
                        <div class="mb-2">
                           <label for="" class="text-sm">Your first / last name</label>
                           <input
                           id="customername"
                           name="name"
                           required
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Your name"
                              class="
                                 mt-2
                                 ring-1 ring-gray-300
                                 w-full
                                 rounded-md
                                 px-4
                                 py-2
                                 outline-none
                                 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-primary
                                 
                              "
                           />
                           <small class="invisible font-medium tracking-wide text-red-500 text-xs  ml-1">Error message</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-2">
                           <label for="" class="text-sm">Email Address</label>
                           <input
                           id="customeremail"
                           name="email"
                           required
                              type="email"
                              placeholder="youremail@example.com"
                              class="mt-2 ring-1 ring-gray-300 w-full rounded-md px-4 py-2 outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-primary"
                           />
                           <small class="invisible font-medium tracking-wide text-red-500 text-xs  ml-1">Error message</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mb-2">
                           <label for="" class="text-sm">Order</label>
                           <textarea
                           id="customerorder"
                           name="order"
                           required
                              type="text"
                              placeholder="Enter item name and quantity here"
                              rows="4"
                              class="mt-2 ring-1 ring-gray-300 w-full rounded-md px-4 py-2 outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-primary"
                           ></textarea>
                           <small class="invisible font-medium tracking-wide text-red-500 text-xs  ml-1">Error message</small>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New PattyKakes Order!">
                        <button class="inline bg-primary self-end text-white font-bold rounded-lg px-6 py-2 uppercase text-sm" type="submit">Submit</button>
                     </form>
                     <!-- form end -->
```

Comment: If you look at source code of your live website there is no JS you posted here or in codepen. You have js/index.js included, and this JS is not there also.